# Can I use a context on multiple items?

Tags: reactjs, nested, use-context

i’m working on a music app, and it has a lot of nested components; eg.

```
<Playlist>
    <Tracklist>
        <Track>
            <TrackPlayButton/>
            <TrackIcon/>
            <TrackData/>
            <TrackActions/>
        </Track>
        <Track>
            <TrackPlayButton/>
            <TrackIcon/>
            <TrackData/>
            <TrackActions/>
        </Track>
        <Track>
            <TrackPlayButton/>
            <TrackIcon/>
            <TrackData/>
            <TrackActions/>
        </Track>
    </Tracklist>
</Playlist>
```

I’ve started to work with `UseContext`, to handle my user data; like checking if a track has been favorited by the user within the `<Track/>` component.

Regarding the user, the logic is simple since I have only *one* user logged, so I only need *one* context.

For tracks, I have a lot of props passing down and down to make my stuff work.

So was thinking about the possibility of using a context for each `<Track/>` : all the components inside a track could use it and it would make things easier to handle.  I would also have a context for the `<Playlist/>`.

But that is where my brain actually breaks:  Is that even possible ?  Could each track have a context?

Maybe you’ll tell me that I would rather use the `<Playlist/>` context to handle the tracks.
But the problem is the same : what if I use multiple `<Playlist/>` in a parent component?

Thank you for all your lights on this :)

Comment: It is possible to use multiple Contexts, but it can get a bit hard to track what is going  on. So generally more in favour of passing props directly.

Comment: Could you give an example of props that need to be passed down? From your example, it's hard to imagine the complexity.